# function gets is not working with a structure

Tags: c

I'm having this function on C language here:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "locale.h"
#include "string.h"
typedef struct aliado {
          char nome[20];
          int forca, agilidade, inteligencia, vida;
    } ALIADO;

ALIADO *atribuicaoAtributos(int classe)
{
    system("cls");

    ALIADO *vet;

    vet = (ALIADO *) malloc(sizeof(ALIADO));

    if(classe==1) {
        printf("NOME DO SEU GUERREIRO: ");
        gets(vet->nome);
        vet->vida = 100;
        vet->forca = 20;
        vet->agilidade = 10;
        vet->inteligencia = 5;
    }

    if(classe==2) {
        printf("NOME DO SEU MAGO: ");
        gets(vet->nome);
        vet->vida = 100;
        vet->forca = 5;
        vet->agilidade = 10;
        vet->inteligencia = 20;
    }

    if(classe==3) {
        printf("NOME DO SEU KILLER: ");
        gets(vet->nome);
        vet->vida = 100;
        vet->forca = 10;
        vet->agilidade = 20;
        vet->inteligencia = 5;
    }

    return vet;
}
```

When I call this function it works fine but when comes to gets(vet->nome), my C program simply ends.

Does anyone know what is happening here?
Here's what's appearing to me:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWk89.png)

Comment: Never use `gets`.  It exists in the language only for backwards compatibility and should *never* be used in new code.

Comment: I tried to use scanf but it didn't work also.

Comment: You didn't specify the struct `ALIADO` in the question. What is the type for the `nome` field. I'm guessing it's a `char*` and you are not allocating memory for that field.

Comment: impossible to answer without knowing what `ALIADO` actually looks like.  If `nome` is `char*`, then clearly you have a problem of failing to allocate memory in which to populate your reads. That's a pure guess, which makes for a lousy answer. Provide the definition of `ALIADO` and a [mcve].

Comment: Hey guys! I did add what ALIADO means. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Zikavírus out of curiosity, look a the top of the source file and tell us: are you, perchance, *missing*, `#include <stdlib.h>` ?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: As of the 2011 standard, `gets` *doesn't* exist in C.

Comment: Please include the output directly in the question, formatted as code using the `{}` button, rather than as a link to an image.

Comment: Why are you casting `vet` to `(ALIADO*)` in `vet = (ALIADO *) malloc(sizeof(ALIADO));`? See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)